# HP All-In-One as a monitor for a gaming PC cuts off some of the display

Tags: display, all-in-one, overscan

I don't have a monitor now, but I decided to use my HP All-In-One as a monitor so I'd be able to play some games at a much higher framerate than my laptop.

The all-in-one does have an HDMI-IN port, and I was able to connect it and have the desktop display appear.

The issue is, most of my screen is cut off unless I apply HDMI scaling. This would be fine, but the picture looks blurry and my mouse movements don't feel smooth at all.

I couldn't find anything online about how to adjust the overscan settings on the all-in-one. I tried changing the scaling settings in Radeon Settings, but no luck. :/

Is there any solution to this other than just using HDMI scaling? If not I will have to live with it, but I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Let me know if there is anything else I should include. Thanks.

Comment: What is the resolution of the all-in-one screen?

Comment: 1920X1080 is the resolution

Comment: Update the graphics driver.